# Dictionary lookup issue from HTTP web service created dictionary

Tags: sharepoint-designer-workflow, dictionary

I am having difficulties getting data from a dictionary I created with an HTTP web service call. I get essentially the same error every time no matter what I have tried.

RequestorId: c378e2d0-e273-451a-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Looking up a value using a key is not supported on an instance of 'Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicPrimitive'. at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicItem.TryGetValue(String key, DynamicItem& value) at Microsoft.Activities.Dynamic.DynamicValueBuilder.PathSegmentFactory.ObjectPathSegment.Get(DynamicItem obj) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Here is my workflow:
[image]

The url I am pulling from has data listed out like this:

[image]

I have tried a plethora of Get xx from xx output xx, but no luck.

d/key, d/results/key, d/results(0)/key, results/key, results(0)/key, key, (0)/key, [%Variable: index%]/key, nwServiceResponse/key, nmSerivceResponse(0)/key

I am at a complete loss at this point. I am pretty new to workflows, dictionaries, and the HTTP web service in Sharepoint. I have googled this quite a bit which is where I got all of the above attempts from. I appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried a plethora of Get xx from xx output xx, but no luck.
>
> d/key, d/results/key, d/results(0)/key, results/key, results(0)/key,
> key, (0)/key, [%Variable: index%]/key, nwServiceResponse/key,
> nmSerivceResponse(0)/key

Because you say you are new to all this, lets take this step by step to help you understand what's going on, and how to figure out what you should be using to get the data you want from the web service response.

Based on the image you provided describing the structure of the data coming from the URL you are calling (which is cropped, so I can't see everything), I am guessing that *some* of it is structured like this:

```
{
    id$: "1",
    customerAccountStatus: null,
    billingSystem: null,
    relatedRecordId: 0,
    statusChanged: false,
    receivedByUserId: "",
    receivedByUserName: "",
    // other stuff
    customerAccountNumber: ""  // <-- not in that image, but looks like what you are trying to get in the workflow
}
```

This gives us an important clue, and based on that, I'd say it looks like you are calling a web service that *is not SharePoint's built in REST web service*. How do I know that?  Because the screenshot of that data does not include a root `d` property.  Which brings us to the first point:

### **When to use `d`**

SharePoint has a built in web service, known as the REST API, that you can call to get data out of SharePoint itself. That root `d` property that you see so much when searching around for examples of SharePoint and web services is something that *is added by SharePoint when you call SharePoint's REST service*.  For example, if you make a query for a single list item:

```
// a query to get (single) list item with ID 5 from the "My List" list
https://my.sharepoint.server/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items(5)
```

the response from SharePoint is going to be structured like:

```
{
    d: {
        Title: "My item's title",
        ID: 5,
        // other SharePoint fields on that list item
    }
}
```

A lot of people use the "Call HTTP Web Service" workflow action to call SharePoint's own REST service and get data out of SharePoint.  In those cases, they need to account for the root `d` property in the response, and use that as part of the "Get item from a dictionary" action.

**However** - you are not limited to calling SharePoint's own web service from "Call HTTP Web Service" in a workflow.  And if you are calling a web service ***outside** SharePoint*, you need to know *how that web service in particular sends its data in its response*.

### **When to use `results` / when to use `(0)`**

These are kind of related, so I am putting them together.  But lets start with `results`.  You see `results` a lot in SharePoint examples because just like `d`, `results` is something that SharePoint itself adds to responses from its own web service.  It adds `results` when the query that you send to SharePoint could *potentially* return more than one item.  In the example in the `d` section above, the query is specifically asking for an item by its ID, so there is only ever going to be a *single* item returned.  But lets say you did a query like this:

```
// a query to get any/all items from the "My List" list where the title is "Foo"

https://my.sharepoint.server/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items?$filter=Title eq 'Foo'
```

You don't know exactly how many items are going to match that query.  Maybe it will be more than one, maybe it will be exactly one, or maybe it will be none.  In *all* of those cases, the response from SharePoint is going to have a `results` array (as a sub-property under the root `d` property - don't forget about the root `d`!):

```
// more than one match
{
    d: {
        results: [
            {
                Title: "Foo",
                ID: 12
            },
            {
                Title: "Foo",
                ID: 31
            },
        ]
    }
}

// exactly one match
{
    d: {
        results: [  // <-- results is still an array, even though it only has one item in it
            {
                Title: "Foo",
                ID: 12
            }
        ]
    }
}

// no matches
{
    d: {
        results: []  // <-- results is still an array, but it's empty!
    }
}
```

This is where we get to using `(0)` - or, more specifically, using the syntax of: a number enclosed in parentheses (doesn't *have* to be zero, necessarily).

You use that syntax to access items in an array, by using their *index* in the array.  So using that example where there was more than one match to the query, you get

```
{
    d: {
        results: [
            {                   // <-- first item is d/results(0) 
                Title: "Foo",
                ID: 12
            },
            {                   // <-- second item is d/results(1)
                Title: "Foo",
                ID: 31
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

A couple important things to note here

- `results` is definitely used by SharePoint in responses from its own
  web service.  It *may or may not* be used in responses from web
  services outside SharePoint - we can't really say without getting a
  result from that other web service and seeing how its data is
  structured, and whether or not that particular web service *also* includes a property called `results`.
- The `(number)` syntax is used in the "Get item from a dictionary" workflow action to index into an array that's part of a web service response, whether or not that response is from SharePoint and whether or not the property that's holding the array is called `results`.

For example, if the response from the web service is structured like:

```
{
    all_the_things: [
        { Bar: "Do" },
        { Bar: "Re" },
        { Bar: "Mi" }
    ]
}
```

and you want to get the value of "Bar" from the third item, you would use

```
all_the_things(2)/Bar
```

Now, in your examples you also list `[%Variable: index%]`.  Where you would use something like that is if you had an array of multiple items, and you wanted to *loop through all of the items*.  Then you use the `index` variable inside the loop to refer to a specific item by its index number, but then increment the `index` variable inside the loop so that the next time through it is one higher, thus accessing the next item in the array.  (Also note that in the example you posted, you actually put `[%Variable: index%]/key`, in which the variable `index` is *not* enclosed in parentheses, therefore it won't actually work as an indexer in the right way.)

So taking the above example again, let's say we set up a loop where we set `index` to `0` before the loop starts, then increment `index` each time through the loop, we would get:

```
all_the_things([%Variable: index%])/Bar // <-- first time through, index is 0, so "Bar" is "Do"

all_the_things([%Variable: index%])/Bar // <-- second time through, index is 1, so "Bar" is "Re"

all_the_things([%Variable: index%])/Bar // <-- third time through, index is 2, so "Bar" is "Mi"
```

### **Getting back to your specific situation**

Going back to your original image of the data returned from the URL you call, I'm making the assumptions that

- You are only getting a single item/object in your response.  I don't see any square brackets `[]` indicating an array or collection of objects, so you don't need to use `(0)`.
- There doesn't *seem* to be a root property like SharePoint's `d` property, it looks like all the property keys are directly on the response object, so you won't need to use anything like `d/FieldName` (or `root/property`, or `rootKey/subKey`, however you want to refer to it conceptually).  But again, your image there is cropped so I can't really be sure - this is where *you* need to understand how the data that's returned to you is structured.

If that's all true, then your "Get.." action should be as simple as

> then Get `propertyNameYouWant` from `Variable: yourResponseDictionary`
> (Output to `Variable: yourVariable`)

which in your specific case looks like you want

> then Get `customerAccountNumber` from `Variable: nwServiceResponse`
> (Output to `Variable: accNum`)

You should *not* have to use the name of your response dictionary variable (`nwServiceResponse`) in the "name or path" part of the "Get..." action, like you have it in the screen shot provided, you should just need the property key name only.

I know you listed using just `key` in the list of all the options you tried, but as far as I can tell from what it looks like the response data is, that should work.

One thing that might help: in order to understand how the response data is structured so you can construct your "Get" path correctly, you need to *see* it.  Usually you can't just log that response dictionary variable to the history list because it's more than likely going to be more than 256 characters.  So... email it to yourself!

Set up a step in the workflow right after the HTTP service call, send an email to yourself, and make the body of the email `[%Variable: nwServiceResponse%]`.  It might be a little hard to figure out at first because it will all be crunched together on one line (which will wrap), but you can put it in a text editor and start to tease it out until you can see the structure. (Or you can put it in VS Code and have it auto-format the JSON in a couple keystrokes ;) )

Comment: I am going to try working on this today. First off though... THANK YOU. This is absolutely phenomenal. I am so grateful that you broke down and explained where /d, /results, etc. came. I am also super glad that you explained how I can view my response data. I was looking for a way to do that so I could better understand it.

Comment: As for the snip of my data, unfortunately there is so much customer and employee sensitive information in the response, I cannot snip more without blacking out every value. If there is something particular you would need to see from the data, I can snip that. However, I am going to work through this first and reply back later.

Thanks again.

Comment: *I did upvote the comment but it doesnt reflect due to my low rep being new :).

Comment: Well I have quickly discovered my issue thanks to the email trick you posted.
"Server Error
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."
We use an SSO that auto logs into the site/data I am viewing. Apparently the sharepoint GET request doesn't have access. I am going to ask my site administer about this. However, I was curious if you know of any way my user credentials could be passed along with the Sharepoint call.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not super familiar with all the ways to pass credentials to web services.  I do know that in some cases you can do it using the headers, so if that were the case for your web service, you could do it by adding the correct properties/values to your request header dictionary in the workflow.